# Why does sun C++ compiler change symbol names when compiling with debug infos?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, solaris, symbols, sun

I have this source file:

```
// ConstPointer.cpp
const short * const const_short_p_const = 0;
const short * const_short_p = 0;
```

and compiled it with and without debug infos (SUN C++ Compiler 5.10):

```
# CC ConstPointer.cpp -c -o ConstPointer.o
# CC -g ConstPointer.cpp -c -o ConstPointer-debug.o
```

Here are the symbol names of the object file **without** debug information:

```
# nm -C ConstPointer.o


ConstPointer.o:

[Index]   Value      Size    Type  Bind  Other Shndx   Name

[2]     |         0|       0|SECT |LOCL |0    |10     |
[3]     |         0|       0|SECT |LOCL |0    |9      |
[4]     |         0|       0|OBJT |LOCL |0    |6      |Bbss.bss
[1]     |         0|       0|FILE |LOCL |0    |ABS    |ConstPointer.cpp
[5]     |         0|       0|OBJT |LOCL |0    |3      |Ddata.data
[6]     |         0|       0|OBJT |LOCL |0    |5      |Dpicdata.picdata
[7]     |         0|       0|OBJT |LOCL |0    |4      |Drodata.rodata
[9]     |         4|       4|OBJT |GLOB |0    |3      |const_short_p
[8]     |         0|       4|OBJT |LOCL |0    |3      |const_short_p_const
```

Here are the symbol names of the object file **with** debug information:

```
# nm -C ConstPointer-debug.o


ConstPointer-debug.o:

[Index]   Value      Size    Type  Bind  Other Shndx   Name

[4]     |         0|       0|SECT |LOCL |0    |9      |
[2]     |         0|       0|SECT |LOCL |0    |8      |
[3]     |         0|       0|SECT |LOCL |0    |10     |
[10]    |         0|       4|OBJT |GLOB |0    |3      |$XAHMCqApZlqO37H.const_short_p_const
[5]     |         0|       0|NOTY |LOCL |0    |6      |Bbss.bss
[1]     |         0|       0|FILE |LOCL |0    |ABS    |ConstPointer.cpp
[6]     |         0|       0|NOTY |LOCL |0    |3      |Ddata.data
[7]     |         0|       0|NOTY |LOCL |0    |5      |Dpicdata.picdata
[8]     |         0|       0|NOTY |LOCL |0    |4      |Drodata.rodata
[9]     |         4|       4|OBJT |GLOB |0    |3      |const_short_p
```

Why has the variable `const_short_p_const` another symbol name? `g++` does not change it, when compiling with debug information. It looks like a compiler bug to me. What do you think? The second `const` (constant pointer) leads to this.

**EDIT for Drew Hall's comment:**
For example you have two files:

```
// ConstPointer.cpp
const short * const const_short_p_const = 0;

void foo();

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
  foo();
  return 0;
}
```

and

```
// ConstPointer2.cpp
extern const short * const const_short_p_const;

void foo() {
  short x = *const_short_p_const;
}
```

Compiling is fine:

```
# CC ConstPointer2.cpp -g -c -o ConstPointer2.o
# CC ConstPointer.cpp -g -c -o ConstPointer.o
```

but linking does not work because the symbols differ! The symbol name in ConstPointer2.o is `const_short_p_const`, but the symbol name in ConstPointer.o is `$XAHMCqApZlqO37H.const_short_p_const`.

```
# CC ConstPointer.o ConstPointer2.o -o ConstPointer
Undefined                       first referenced
 symbol                             in file
const_short_p_const                 ConstPointer2.o
```

Comment: This is purely an implementation detail--why are you concerned with the generated symbol names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this is linked to the fact that a global `const` variable is implicitely `static` in C++?

Comment: Certainly.  If you look at the output he posted, without debug information, the binding is local; with it, the binding is global.  (I suspect that the motivation here is that once you link, all local symbols disappear.)  Fundamentally, with debug symbols, Sun CC is treating `static` more or less as if it were in an anonymous namespace.

Comment: Yeah, in C++ global const variables are implictly static, unless you explicitly declare them `extern`. This allows to compile and link the above example with the two files!